# Google Analytics API displaying a single account

Tags: oauth, google-analytics, oauth-2.0, google-analytics-api

I've been working with the Google Analytics API to create a page showing some specific statistics.  Right now everything is working, except that after the user goes through OAuth, it is displaying statistics from their Google Account.

Instead, I always want it to display statistics from a single Google Account that I own/operate, and everyone else is just viewing the data from that account.

I haven't seen a way in the GA documentation to accomplish this.  I would assume the user wouldn't have to log in, because I'm just showing them my account, but it's not the end of the world if they have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to create a place where users do not have to go through OAuth, you should really look at using Google's [superProxy](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-super-proxy) to publicly display data.